# Como usar o ternário aqui?

Tags: php, operadores

```
$rs = $pbc->selectPublication(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_DEFAULT));
```

Tenho esse código que é passado como argumento do método para selecionar os posts no sistema, mas como posso usar ele com ternário, caso ele retorne true e seja filtrado sem problemas passe o valor, ou se der algum problema, envie 0?

Minha classe select:

```
$selectSQL = $this->pdo->prepare('SELECT values WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1');

            $selectSQL->bindValue(1, $codigo, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $selectSQL->execute();
            $row = $selectSQL->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return $row;
```

Comment: Qual o retorno dele, caso dê erro?

Comment: 0,  ou se der algum problema, envie 0.

Comment: Se o retorno dele, quando dá erro, já é zero, por que você precisa de um ternário?

Comment: Não sabia que retorna 0

Comment: Ah, achei que tu tinha falado que retornava zero.

Comment: Mas tem como você colar o método `selectPublication` para facilitar a resposta?

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = $pbc->selectPublication(filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_DEFAULT));

echo ($rs) ? $rs : '0';
```

Se a variável tem retorno, então ou ela tem "conteúdo" ou é 0 ou false correto ?!
Com isso:

```
$rs = true;
echo ($rs) ? $rs : '0';
$rs = false;
echo ($rs) ? $rs : '0';
$rs = 'okok';
echo ($rs) ? $rs : '0';
// pegadinha
$rs = 'false';
echo ($rs) ? $rs : '0';
```

Comment: Como isso ($rs) ? $rs : '0'; funciona? Coloque na resposta por favor.

Comment: É assim que comenta na resposta ? nunca usei stack

Comment: Cara como assim dá -1 !? 
Pode-se ter vários entendimentos da questão, como vários resultados... peloamor...

Comment: Amigo, não fui eu que dei -1

Comment: Foi o Felipe Avelar então... que sacanagem...

Comment: A certos comentários que devem ser evitados, leia aqui, vai te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment